# Order by Collection entity property in ASP.NET MVC 3 (entity framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, sql-order-by

I have two entities like:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeEducation> EducationList { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class EmployeeEducation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

}
```

My question is, how can I get a specific employee and this employee's education list ordered by **Type** property?

I have tried:

```
Employee employee = _work.EmployeeRepository.GetSet()
    .SelectMany(e => e.EducationList, (e,d) => new { e, d })
        .OrderBy(x => x.d.Type)
        .Select(x => x.e)
   .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

But it does't seem to be sorting. What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks for everyone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `SelectMany()`, but never use the produced `EducationList` part, becuase you do `.Select(x => x.e)`. But couldn't life be simpler? After all, you only get 1 employee, why not sort its `EducationList` as soon as you need it, after having `Include`d it, if necessary:

```
Employee employee = _work.EmployeeRepository.GetSet().Include("EducationList")
.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

Comment: Yes, but I need education list also. I want to select one employee and education list of this employee sorted by education type.

Comment: That's what you get with `Include`, don't you? You can do `employee.EducationList.OrderBy(...` after getting the employee. Or am I missing some point you made?

Comment: You are right, it is my fault. Do you offer me to do `Employee.EducationList = employee.EducationList.OrderBy` after getting employee? I probably need to learn this subject from scratch...

Comment: No, I mean: order it when you need it. Replacing it by an ordered collection is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you! Eventually I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending if u are using POCO or not u should either use [CreateSourceQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896438.aspx) or Query()
In the case of POCO something like:

```
Employee employee = _work.EmployeeRepository.GetSet()
    .SelectMany(e => e.EducationList, (e,d) => new { e, d })
        .Query()
        .OrderBy(x => x.d.Type)
        .Select(x => x.e)
   .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why; but there is no CreateSourceQuery or Query methods for me:(